# Using an image with a button with kivy, invalid data error

Tags: image, button, kivy

I'm getting an invalid data after declaration error. This appears to be similar to what the kivy documentation shows on how it uses images as the button pictures... but I'm obviously getting something wrong.

Heres my .kv file, any idea why I would be getting this issue?

```
 #:kivy 1.9.2
<YourWidget>:
BoxLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Button:
            id: btn1
            text: "Change Text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
            size_hint: 1, 1

        Button:
            id: btn2
            text: "Exit App"
            on_release: root.ExitApp()
            size_hint: 1, 1

        Label:
            id: lbl1
            font_size: 15
            text:root.random_number
            size_hint: 1, 1
        Label:
            id: lblTemp
            font_size: 15
            text:root.tempProbe1
            size_hint: 1, 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Label:
            id: lblErrors
            text: root.currentError
            font_size: 15
            size_hint: 1, 1

        Button:
            id: btn4
            text: root.button4status
    background_down: 'led1.png'
    on_press: root.button4pressed()
            size_hint: 1, 1

        Label:
            id: lbl2
            font_size: 15
            text:root.button4status
            size_hint: 1, 1

        Label:
            id: lbl3
            font_size: 15
            text: "Unused Currently"
            size_hint: 1, 1
```

Comment: your indentation seems to be off, at least in the posted code

Comment: Yeah it wasn't on my raspberry pi. Not like it shows there anyway, I just noticed that. It seemed correct in my file, but once I deleted the indents and made it more exact by uses the perfect amount of spaces the program began to work.